Should I mention a junk citation?
I am writing down an application to a professorship, and among several other documents a list of all the papers* that cite mine is required (I suspect this is somewhat unusual to most readers, but where I live this is commonplace).
I was updating myself on the papers that cite mine, just to be sure I didn't miss any, and lo and behold there was a new one: as I always do I checked how they used my work (this is possible because I still have very few citations, sadly), and I found out the paper is junk. To be precise, this is in Mathematics and the author seems to be a crackpot (and this is not really a guess, the paper is less than 10 pages long, has no explanation for its results, and proves the inconsistency of Mathematics).
Question: should I add this paper to the list of papers that cite mine?
On one hand, I feel that it may look deceitful not to mention it: people evaluating my list may feel that I'm omitting it so that some junk research is not associated with me. On the other, I doubt they would actually check the list, and will probably just write down the number of items in it: in this case I am losing one citation, but it is not one that I mind losing... I am not sure of what to do...
*: this includes published, peer-reviewed studies, as well as sometimes preprints, as it is the case with the one I currently describe.

You have no control over the actions of others. One would hope that whomever is using the list would recognize that.

I'm puzzled how this is feasible for most people - I'm a relatively low level academic, I have almost 3000 citations of my various papers, in order to produce such a list, I'd need to spend a lot of time writing a script to combine the lists of papers that cite each of my papers and then remove the duplicates (papers that cite multiple of my papers), there's certainly no way I could feasibly read all these papers and decide if they are nonsense.

@RachelC To be fair, I never said this is reasonable for most people! These lists are usually a requirement for applications to tenured-track positions, and a lot of people will only get accepted to one of these once, early-ish in their carriers, when the citation count is not too high. Plus, what field are you in that you have 3000 citations and consider yourself a low level academic!? I like to think I'm a somewhat successful researcher in my field,  and I'm still on double digits...

You should clarify the meaning of the word "paper": Does it mean a publication or does it include preprints? In math, the standard thing to do would be to use MathSchiNet to collect references to one's work. If you use this, then (I guess) a crackpot paper simply will not appear on the list and you can make a footnote that references are collected using MathSchiNet.

Just do it like google. Omit the citation, and write a comment below: "Due to questionable quality, one paper was omitted." (Do not do this! It would just set the focus to this paper and you will end naming the paper)

@MoisheKohan It is actually demanded that we use more than one "citation-listing" service, so in MathSciNet this paper really disappears. But Google Scholar is required, and there one finds a few preprints, such as this one (which probably won't ever get published).

You should clarify all this by editing the question, as comments are supposed to be ephemeral and can disappear at any time. In particular, clarify the meaning of the word "paper."

@MoisheKohan I was in the process of editing it!

@GVT I think math is very low in citation counts (although, I am still amazed by a "low-level academic" having 3000 citations too!).

@MoisheKohan Even crackpot papers can be reviewed in MathSciNet (and these reviews can be a lot of fun, both to write and to read).

@AzorAhai-him- My PhD advisor, who is close to retirement, hasn't reached 3000 citations WITH duplicates! But yes, it's one of those things that are field-dependent.


I feel that it may look deceitful not to mention it

Well, it sort of is deceitful, isn't it? You are asked to provide a list of all the papers citing your work, and you want to intentionally withhold a paper you are aware of and not put it on the list. It may be a well-intentioned deceit, but it does seem like it would be a deceit. Why wouldn't you just give a truthful answer to the question you are being asked?
If you are concerned that this citation is undeserved, or want to dissociate yourself from the contents of a junk paper, add a footnote in your list that expresses that you have some doubts as to whether this is a credible scientific paper (no need to say you're certain it's a junk paper; the people reading your list can look at it and make up their own minds if the question interests them). Then no one will suspect you of dishonesty or deceit, and you wouldn't have to worry that you may be acting out of ignoble or dishonorable motives by listing the paper.

@GVT I must say that my response missed the part in your question where OP is required to list all citing papers (although this sounds an absurd task in all but the most junior scientists' cases). In that case, Dan's response is probably more appropriate. You should not intentionally leave off a citation that you know about if you are required to list them. Dan's suggestion of a footnote is a good solution to make clear that you are aware of a dodgy citation.

I think the idea of a footnote is brilliant: I am worried that if I have this paper on the list it may seem like I'm profiting from junk research, but I can clarify that on the note, and if anyone is feeling specially curious they can always look at the paper themselves and see the reason for the footnote!

@gvt well you can't exactly make the citation to away, why would someone hold that against you?

@DonQuiKong OP has two valid concerns here about just listing the citation without comment: 1. other people may get the (probably incorrect) idea that OP is trying to profit from a junk paper citing their work. 2. OP may question their own motives in listing the citation and may not want to feel as if they are profiting off of listing the citation. The footnote idea should address both of these concerns: it lets you give an answer that is both truthful and avoids perverse incentives. And if the institution then still insists on giving OP credit for a bogus citation, that's on them.

@DanRomik Basically, it's a special case of the more general rule: if in doubt if something is above water or if it constitutes a conflict of interest, make it transparent and give a disclaimer. This is the proper way to deal with such issues. I upvoted the response as it is a more apt one for the specific case of OP than mine. I left mine around for the more generic case, where there is not the specific requirement to list all citations.

I think the upvotes clearly show a consensus that this is the best way forward: the straightforward idea of explaining in a footnote the paper's results are not beyond suspicion never occurred to me, but it is definitely what I plan to do!

Why use it?
Citations show that people value your work or consider it relevant to what they do. However, for that, the reputation of the citing work matters.
If you get random social influencers to cite you - how does it support your esteem level amongst your scientific community if none of these influencers has scientific credentials?
Listing a citation by a crackpot does not add to your reputation; you do not need it. In fact, it would appear as if you put value on it. This, in turn, implies that you might be desperate for recognition.
On the other hand, as you worry that by not mentioning it, it would appear as if you are hiding it: this is not on you. Say, you had some some well-executed scientific work on genes without ulterior agenda. Now this work happens to be cited by people with a shady agenda to justify nefarious eugenic positions. How would that be on you?
If you happened to discover some, say, pseudo-Lamarckian epigenetic phenomena in a clean study, published in a serious journal. Then someone abuses it to "justify" creationism - how would that be your fault?
Not to mention agenda-driven mis-interpretations of scientific studies about topics such as climate.
You cannot stop people from citing you, in a way that does not not act in good scientific faith, to support their case.
But mentioning them would sound as if you give them at least a sufficient credential that they are worth being listed.
The one case where I would probably mention a mis-citation at all, is if a popular misleading piece of work abuses your work to support a false, damaging, malign or otherwise problematic position - but the right place for this would be a public scientific or publicity debate, not the CV for your application.

I think this is more or less what I was thinking myself, but it is good to know that other researchers have the same opinion.
